# When do I have to put 'a' before 'one' as a pronoun?

Tags: articles

I wonder if there is a rule on that score. Judging from the examples below, it just looks as if you don't put ***a*** when ***one*** goes alone, and you have to use it when ***one*** goes with an adjective. Am I wrong?

> We've run out of clean towels. - It's ok, I have a spare one.
>
> I was looking for a clean towel but couldn't find one.
>
> What towel would you like? - Just an ordinary one, I don't really
>   care.
>
> Can I have a towel? - Go to the bathroom and take one.
>
> Did you buy me a towel? - Yes, a big yellow one.

Comment: You're not wrong, but either article is OK. When the pronoun _one_ is preceded by an adjective, it can take either the definite or indefinite: _Can I have a/the warm one?_ When used without a preceding adjective, it takes the zero article or the definite: _Can I have one? Can I have the one with feathers?_ (Note that the plural must take either the zero or the definite, but never the indefinite, when preceded by an adjective: _Can I have the warm ones? Can I have warm ones?_)

Comment: @P.E.Dant that comment can be the answer!

Comment: @P.E.Dant - agreed, but note that "a warm one" implies that they need to find or make a warm one, whereas "the warm one" implies that there are both cold and warm ones already to hand. Implies...

Answer (score 6):

In older grammars, ***one*** when used in this way was referred to as a *pronoun,* just as you do in the title of your question. At first glance, it does seem to act as a pronoun: it stands *for* (pro-) a noun.

However, this categorization introduced an inconsistency: because in this usage it is grammatically correct when preceded by a determiner, *one* doesn't fit in the syntactic class of pronouns. It also inflects in number, unlike other pronouns. Compare:

> <sup>**✅**</sup> Is that the *one?*
>   <sup>**NG**</sup> Is that the *it?*
>
> <sup>**✅**</sup> Which *ones* do you want?
>   <sup>**NG**</sup> Which *its* do you want?

The word **one** is used in your examples as what some traditional grammars (Jesperson, e.g.) called a [*prop-word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prop-word).

OED includes a description of this usage under "Pronoun," but with qualifications, and without a modern example:

> **V.** As substitute for a noun or noun phrase.
>   **13.** Following a determiner such as *the, this, that, yon, any, each, every, many (a), other, such (a), what (a), what kind of (a), which,* or (in certain phrases) following *a,* or (from Middle English onwards) following an ordinary adjective (occas. also a noun used attributively) preceded by any of these or (in plural) alone.
>
> **a.** A thing or person (or, in plural, things or persons) of the kind in question (as indicated by the context).
>
> > <sup>Down to the late Middle English period *one* was probably felt as an emphatic pronoun, intensifying the determiner with which it was coupled. In modern English it is generally an empty pro-form **(sometimes referred to as a ‘prop-word’)**, and the addition of *one* or *ones* often serves to specify number: cf. ‘Which do you choose?’ with ‘Which one do you choose?’ ‘Which ones do you choose?’   (Emphasis mine.)</sup>

The [*Oxford dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/one) (n.b.: *not* the OED) refers to this usage, without elaboration, as a *pronoun:*

> **PRONOUN**
>
> 1. Referring to a person or thing previously mentioned or easily identified.
>      *‘her mood changed from one of moroseness to one of joy’
>
>      ‘her best apron, the white one’
>
>      ‘do you want one?’*

Modern grammars like CGEL ([as Araucaria points out here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/288859/192771)) solve the problem by referring to *one* in this usage as a *Determinative occurring in a fused Determiner Head construction.*

Consider the response portion of your last example:

> Yes, a big yellow one.

Here, the single word *one* is, and functions as, a *noun phrase.* It has the same grammatical properties as the word it represents: *towel,* and we treat it just like a noun. A linguist might tell you that this *one* is the ***anamorphic "one:"*** it depends for its content on the context in which it is used. As Araucaria says [**here:**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288817/how-can-a-pronoun-one-be-a-noun#comment645840_288859)

> "It's just an unusual noun because we use it like a blank Scrabble tile."

If it is preceded by an adjective, it must take either the *definite* or *indefinite* article, but never the *zero article*:

> Can I have *a* warm one<sup>(towel)</sup>?
>   Can I have *the* warm one?
>   <sup>**never**</sup> Can I have warm one?

When it is used *without* a preceding adjective, it takes the *zero article* or the *definite* article, and never the *indefinite* article:

> Can I have one<sup>(*a* towel)</sup> with feathers?
>   Can I have *the* one with feathers?
>   <sup>**never**</sup> Can I have *a* one with feathers?

The plural **ones** *must* take either the zero or the definite article, but never the indefinite article, when it is preceded by an adjective:

> Can I have *the* warm ones<sup>(towels)</sup>?
>   Can I have warm ones?
>   <sup>**never**</sup> Can I have *a* warm ones?

Comment: Nice answer. Just one thing, I don't think that *one* in that phrase is a pronoun. We can consider it as a Pro-form of a noun. Just like the verb *do* can act as the pro-form of another verb.

Comment: @Man_From_India Right, *one* doesn't have the syntactic features we expect of a pronoun, so we can't say it's "used as a pronoun" here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Jespersen, right? Google says that Jesperson is a serial killer...

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov "Google says?" Pray tell, how does Google "say" this? Google is an index of websites, and anyone at all can publish whatever she pleases on her website. I could publish a website which states that "George Sovetov" is playing at silly buggers, for instance. Now, there _was_ a serial killer with the surname "Jesperson", but he was not related to our Otto.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: pronouns don't take articles.

However, noun phrases do and this is what you are seeing in your examples. In *a spare one* for example, *spare one* is a noun phrase which takes the article *a*. Similarly, in *a big yellow one*, the phrase *big yellow one* is a noun phrase. This can be confirmed by replacing the noun phrases with a noun.

The presence of adjectives has little to do with it. While it is difficult to imagine noun phrase without adjectives, it is not the presence of the adjectives that is governing the grammar. It is the presence of the noun phrase containing the adjectives.

Comment: So: in the sentence "That's the one I want," you believe that _one_ is not a pronoun. Is that correct? What is it, then?

Comment: Where did I say it isn't a pronoun?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your declarative sentence above: _Simple answer: pronouns don't take articles._

Comment: Did you also read the sentence that comes directly after it? A pronoun appearing within a phrase (or clause) does not stop being a pronoun, but the preceding article acts **on the phrase**, not the pronoun alone.

Comment: Tell me then: in the sentence _That is the one,_ where is the noun phrase?

Comment: @P.E.Dant and RF NP don't take articles. When a nominal takes a determiner it forms a NP. Preposition can replace a NP. But here this *one* in *the spare one* is not a pronoun. It's the pro-form of noun.

Comment: A phrase contains head words along with modifies and complements. A pronoun as far as I can think right now doesn't generally takes a modifier, nor it takes a complement. So how can a pronoun make a phrase that it heads? No idea.

Comment: @Man_From_India ~ a noun phrase can take an article. *The big cat* is a noun phrase. It has an article. *Big cats* is also a noun phrase, without an article, so the article does not define define a noun phrase. Maybe you heard of the DP hypothesis? That is largely discredited now.  As for 'one' being a pronoun, in *a spare one*, one is replacing 'towel' (*a spare towel*) so to that extent it is a pronoun -> http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/one_2

Comment: What is DP hypothesis?

Comment: It was an idea around in, from memory, the 1990s that said that noun phrases should be called determiner phrases, with the determiner as the head. This meant that the determiner became the defining feature, which is why I thought you might have had that in mind.

Comment: No then I didn't mean that. DP + Nominal = Noun Phrase. The head of that NP is still a noun.

Comment: @Man_From_India Ref. "DP hypothesis," see [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase) Current score in the conflict appears to have the NP side up by a clear magin.

Comment: @P.E.Dant thanks, but I didn't mean that!

Comment: @Man_From_India It's interesting reading, anyway. It's always good to know what is being contested amongst...the sort who contest such things.  :)